# Office Script (Excel Online) - GET UserName or Email

Tags: excel, office-scripts

Normally if we want to get de user name and set to a specific cell in VBA we do this:
.Cells(2, 10).Value = Application.UserName

**So how we can do the same in Office Script ?**

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported. The Excel.Identity interface is currently in preview in Office.js. So it will take some time until it gets pushed into the production version of the API. And from there, until it gets pushed to Office Scripts. You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.identity?view=excel-js-preview